# Probabilistic linebreaking algorithm

Tags: dynamic-programming, markov-chains

I'm currently trying to implement this [paper](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~remco/line.report.pdf):

*Bouckaert, Remco R.*, [**A probabilistic line breaking algorithm**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b94701), Gedeon, Tamás D. (ed.) et al., AI 2003: Advances in Artificial Intelligence. 16th Australian conference on AI, Perth, Australia, December 3--5, 2003. Proceedings. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-20646-9/pbk). Lecture Notes in Computer Science 2903. Lecture Notes in Artificial Intelligence, 390-401 (2003). [ZBL1205.68488](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1205.68488).

Based on a bayesian network, the paper stays unclear about how to ultimately use its content ("straightforward inference").  But after a lot of researches (I have no background in that field), I think I can apply Viterbi algorithm to get the expected result. I will give here a description of my problem but as I might have misunderstood some things, the non biased description of the algorithm is available Section 3.1 of the paper.

We try to find a set of breakpoint $S$.

The test case is "aaa bb cc ddddd" with text width 6 which should result in:

```
aaa
bb cc
ddddd
```

which is a set of breakpoints $S = \{0,1,3,(4?)\}$. Just for information, for the test, I use `o-=14` and `o+=3` to get more manageable results (ref. paper).

We try to find the boolean value of $i \in S$ for each word (character in the paper). We start with the beginning of the paragraph with `nlw0=0` (`nwli` is the width of a line from previous breakpoint) and $0 \in S$.

First take next token `c1 = "aaa"` with width `cw1 = 3`.

So, trying to use the Viterbi algorithm, I explore both possibilities of $i \in S$ and $i \not\in S$. It leaves us with two paths, set of breakpoints with `nlwi = 3` (`Pa` is described page 7):

`{0,1}` with `Pa(0, -6)≅0.8713`
and `{0}` with `Pa = 1`

No choices here to make so it's seems okay. But I'm not sure if I even use `Pa` the right way...

Then I tried a few things which all ended wrong. It more or less looked like this:

Take next token `cw2`, try all possibilities and keep only the best ones for `2 ∈ S` and `2 ∉ S`.

It gives use 4 different sets:

`{0,2}` with `Pa(3, -3) 4.45` product previous `Pa`. `Total≅ 4.45`
`{0,1,2}` with `Pa(3, -3)≅ 4.45` product previous `Pa`. `Total≅ 3.877`
`{0}` `Pa=1`. `Total=1`
`{0,1}` `Pa=1`. `Total≅ 0.8713`

The best two sets we keep are `{0,2}` and `{0}` which already discards the expected result. Anyway I usually end up with no breakups at all...

So I'm probably missing something important. There are a few things I don't get in the paper either:

- What is node `bi` used for?
- and why is `Pa` described as the "acceptability of breaking-up up to `ci` instead of `ci-1`?

Comment: Isn't `P_a` the probability function? Why do you have values outside of `[0,1]`?

Comment: Hum. Yes, I think `Pa` is the probability function or at least I treated that way. What do you mean by "outside [0,1]"? "[0,1]" is a set of indexes for which `i ∈ S`.

Comment: By `[0,1]` I mean the interval from 0 to 1, which is where probability values are valid.

Comment: In my code (in clojure), I keep them together in a record `{:breakups [0, 1], :acceptability 0.873}` . As I understand the probability of a path at i as the probability of i-1 multiplied by current `Pa` so I don't need to keep them further, do I?

Comment: Correct, you shouldn't need to store previous intermediate probabilities, but you might want to for debugging.  I'm just asking why are you getting a probability value of 4.45?  That doesn't make any sense - you can't have probabilities greater than 1.

Comment: I use the definition of `Pa` from the paper: more or less `N(x+y, o)/N(x, o)` ,`N` being a normal defined page 7 when breaking at i. 1 if not breaking. If `0<Pa<1`, there would be no breakpoints as not breaking would always have maximum probability.